# Filter a PHP array of objects by a common ID

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am working on a property site, which pulls results from a CRM database. The results pulled back are based on available units within a larger property (i.e. one big block that houses various apartments). I need to be able to push in an array of images per property but NOT per unit, but the result array brings back each property and each unit. Here's what I mean:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [property_id] => 2
            [unit_id] => 5
            [property_name] => Morb House
            [address] => 123 Test Street, Blahtown, BL1 AHH
            [unit_name] => Apartment Number 1
            [max_guests] => 2
            [description] => This is a nice place
            [bedrooms] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [property_id] => 2
            [unit_id] => 6
            [property_name] => Morb House
            [address] => Some Road, Some Town, Anywhere
            [unit_name] => Apartment Number 2
            [max_guests] => 4
            [description] => This is a slightly bigger place
            [bedrooms] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [property_id] => 2
            [unit_id] => 11
            [property_name] => Morb House
            [address] => 123 Test Street, Blahtown, BL1 AHH
            [unit_name] => Cool Studio
            [max_guests] => 1
            [description] => This is a teeny weeny place
            [bedrooms] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [property_id] => 4
            [unit_id] => 12
            [property_name] => Fake Buildings
            [address] => 1 Fake Street, Anytown
            [unit_name] => Fake Apartment One
            [max_guests] => 1
            [description] => Some description here
            [bedrooms] => 1
        )

)
```

The images that I will fetch from another table will be filtered by property ID, which I intend to add to the object that pertains to that property. However, since there are multiple units available to book within a single property, that property ID is duplicated in the first 3 results. Ideally, I'd like my result to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [property_id] => 2
            [property_name] => Morb House
            [address] => 123 Test Street, Blahtown, BL1 AHH
            [units] => Array
            (
                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [unit_name] => Apartment Number 1
                        [max_guests] => 2
                        [description] => This is a nice place
                        [bedrooms] => 1
                    )
                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [unit_name] => Apartment Number 2
                        [max_guests] => 4
                        [description] => This is a slightly bigger place
                        [bedrooms] => 2
                    )
                [11] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [unit_name] => Cool Studio
                        [max_guests] => 1
                        [description] => This is a teeny weeny place
                        [bedrooms] => 1
                    )

            )
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [property_id] => 4
            [property_name] => Fake Buildings
            [address] => 1 Fake Street, Anytown
            [units] => Array
            (
                [12] => stdClass Object 
                    (
                        [unit_name] => Fake Apartment One
                        [max_guests] => 1
                        [description] => Some description here
                        [bedrooms] => 1
                    )
            )

        )

)
```

Where the keys are actually the property IDs, and there is a sub-object of each unit within that property, keyed by the relevant unit IDs.

I just need some advice on how to do this simply and cleanly in the PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
$out=array();
foreach($array as $item)
{
   $new = new StdClass;
   foreach(array('unit_name','max_guests','description','bedrooms') as $add){
     $new->{$add} = $item->{$add};
   }
   if(isset($item[$item->property_id])){
         $out[$item->property_id]->units[$item->unit_id] = $new; 
         continue;
   }
   $out[$item->property_id] = (object)array('property_id'=>$item->property_id,'property_name'=>$item->property_name,'address'=>$item->address,'units'=>array($item->unit_id=>$new));
}
print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way you can get that format you want is if you are using ORM with proper relationship settings for your properties and units table. if not, then you have to transform your existing result to the format you want.

e.g.

```
<?php

// your current result set goes here
$units = $your_crm->database->get_units();

$properties = [];

foreach ($units as $_unit)
{
    $id = $_unit->property_id;

    $unit = [
        'unit_name'   => $_unit->unit_name,
        'max_guests'  => $_unit->max_guests,
        'description' => $_unit->description,
        'bedrooms'    => $_unit->bedrooms,
    ];

    if (isset($properties[$id])) {
        $properties[$id]->units[] = $unit;
    } else {
        $properties[$id] = (object) [
            'property_id'   => $_unit->property_id,
            'property_name' => $_unit->property_name,
            'address'       => $_unit->address,
            'units'         => [$unit]
        ];
    }
}

print_r($properties);
```